# Central Message Manager for managing different messages between different classes

Tags: c#, wpf, design-patterns, software-design

I am writing an application in C#. Now i am thinking over and over again about its design. Have already changed my mind 3 or 4 times but thankfully for the good.

After few iterations i come up with a solution but i am still wondering what is the best way to achieve that with C#.

Basically i will have a class lets call it `MessageManager`, and after each action different classes will send a message to `MessageManager` and `MessageManager` will send the message depending on the response. Then i will have another manager call it `UIManager` it will perform all the UI switching or inform the `MessageManager` in case of any core/helper operation is required.

Now the thing is messages could make up to like 50-60 types each will have different type of arguments. And i want to design it in a way if i have new messages in future it can accommodate that as well.

What is the best way to accomplish that in C# like what will be the best for such case delegates, events. Flexibility is the most important thing.

Comment: Why don't just use some MVVM framework? [Caliburn](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/) has a very powerful messaging service, though the starting with the framework itself is a little complicated. [MVVM Light](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) also has a good messenger, and require virtually no setup.

Comment: In a way i want to stick to what .Net offers, working with .net for a week or so. And i prefer to use what it already offers to get to know more of its insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that combining the Observer pattern (publish/subscribe logic) along side with the Mediator one can be a good solution to your problem. Your Mediator class will act as an Event Manager (most of your classes will depend on it as a mediator rather than depending on each others) :

```
public class MessageManager{

    private Dictionary<string,List<MessageListener>> listeners;

    public void sendMessage(Message m){
        //loop over listeners of m
    }

    public void addMessageListener(MessageListener ml){
         //add a listener
    }

    public void removeMessageListener(MessageListener ml){
         //remove a listener
    }
}
```

`Message` would be the parent interface, having a generic abstraction at this level is very important as it avoids the `MessageManager` from distinguishing between your 50-60 types of messages and thus becoming a nightmare to maintain. The specificity of depending on a particular sub-type of `Message` should be moved to a lower level: the direct consumers.

Comment: But what about the other way round, for example `MessageManager` sends a message to `Client1` and it completed the task (passed/failed), now `Client1` will need to inform `MessageManager` about its completion so the message for the next operation can be send. I am mixing it up a bit. Could you kindly explain it a bit more. Thanks

Comment: Client1 can send/trigger either ClientMessageSuccess, ClientMessageFailure. The listeners for those messages will be informed, take appropriate actions and trigger/send the appropriate event/message if necessary.

Comment: There is one more thing that pops up into my mind regarding this approach, the mediator part specifically facilitating, class to class messaging which i should avoid because of the complexity of the application rather i would prefer a central controller that should decide what to do next. Any thoughts?

Comment: Well, there is no reason that your controller will be less complex than a Mediator. Deciding on what to do next will be translated into a behavior that will be implemented by some methods. To me this logic should remain in your Client. The mediator is like a traffic light it tells you that it's red, but it's up to the driver that looks a it to stop.

Comment: After doing some more research and looking at many options, i came to the conclusion the design you propose fits best to my need. Thanks for all the effort.